# How do I set up GRUB to display on 2 monitors?

Tags: boot, nvidia, grub2, external-monitor

How do I set up GRUB to display on 2 monitors?

I have a laptop plugged in to a external monitor. Most of the time, I leave the laptop closed, and just use the monitor, but when I boot up, I have to open the lid to select GRUB boot option.

I don't want to set the config to be only the external monitor in case I am not plugged in to one. So I figure a mirrored config would be best.

I have an NVidia m360 card if info is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRUB displays on the monitor that is given to it by the hardware and as far as I know it can only be one at that point in the boot process.

Your laptop might have a function button that lets you choose the output a bit more easily for when you don't have the extra monitor attached and it may even default back to the laptop display if it doesn't see an external monitor. The only way to really know though is to give it a try.